# Replace {"errors":{"detail":"Not Found"}} with message in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script with python to extract stuff from a .pcap file. The output is written to a .csv file. This is what I have so far:
(please ignore the Dutch words, they are only for notes and names)

```
import csv
from encodings import utf_8
from enum import unique
import time
import dpkt.ethernet
import requests
import pyshark

from dpkt.utils import mac_to_str

#Opvragen bestand:
bestand = input("Voer hier het hele pad in naar de pcap(ng): ")

#Pcap reader inzetten:
f = open(bestand, 'rb')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

#In de lege lijst worden de MAC addressen gezet:
maclist = []

#Voegt de source en destination toe in de maclist:
for timestamp, buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    x = mac_to_str(eth.src)
    y = mac_to_str(eth.dst)
    maclist.append(x)
    maclist.append(y)

uniqueList = set(maclist)

#Schrijven naar een .csv bestand:
with open("output.csv", "w",encoding="UTF8") as a:
    writer  = csv.writer(a)

    for addr in uniqueList:
        extra = str(requests.get('http://api.macvendors.com/' + addr).text)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"MAC: {addr}, Fabrikant/serie/model: {extra}")
          
        writer.writerow([addr] + [extra])
    print("Zie ouput.csv voor het resultaat!")
```

Unfortunally, sometimes my output looks like this:

```
MAC: <private>, Fabrikant/serie/model: {"errors":{"detail":"Not Found"}}
```

Is there a way to replace this? It would make my output look a bit cleaner.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: `if extra == '{"errors":{"detail":"Not Found"}}': extra = "Not Found"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of extra and either skip the writing:

```
for addr in uniqueList:
    extra = str(requests.get('http://api.macvendors.com/' + addr).text)
    if extra == '{"errors":{"detail":"Not Found"}}':
         continue
```

or replace it with something else, as the comments suggested

```
for addr in uniqueList:
    extra = str(requests.get('http://api.macvendors.com/' + addr).text)
    if extra == '{"errors":{"detail":"Not Found"}}':
         extra = "Not Found"
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked!